# pyspark 'Index' object is not callable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is a copy and paste line from a data science experiment I am trying to run.

```
for col,num in zip(df.toPandas().describe().columns(),range(1,11)):
```

It shows output but not on Databricks.

Error is:

```
TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you can't call an index object, which is `df.toPandas().describe().columns`. Try removing the brackets:

```
for (col, num) in zip(df.toPandas().describe().columns, range(1,11)):
```

perhaps a better way is to use `enumerate` instead of `zip`, which avoids the need to hard code the number of columns:

```
for (num, col) in enumerate(df.toPandas().describe().columns):
```

Comment: It was copied from something that shows output. Crappy

Comment: Maybe some versioning problems?

Comment: Although I don't remember any recent pandas versions which calls `columns`

Comment: enumerate did not work, the other did. You beaut.

Comment: I am helping u get that 10K. It's amazing.

Comment: ah, enumerate starts from 0, so you need to add 1 to num inside the for loop.

Comment: haha, thanks for the help, you don't have to worry about me :)

Comment: "help" is a very broad def. Cheers